# How do I activate VS2010's Process Debug Manager for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, com

I've got a server application (**not** a website, not HTML- or browser-based) that provides extensibility in the form of JavaScript scripts.  Theoretically, I'm supposed to be able to debug them with Visual Studio's debugger through something called the Process Debug Manager.

I have VS2010 properly installed and activated, but when I call CoCreateInstance, like so:

```
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ProcessDebugManager, nil,
  CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IProcessDebugManager, _PDM);
```

it returns `$80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)`, which [is not documented behavior for `CoCreateInstance`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  The documentation, however, describes an alternative way to do the same thing, with `CoGetClassObject`.  When I try that, it returns `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG`, meaning that the CLSID is not registered in the Registry.

So what do I have to do to register VS2010's script debugger in the Registry so I can run Process Debug Manager?

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG, you are probably mixing 32- and 64-bit stuff:  probably you're trying to call CoCreateInstance from a 64-bit program, unless you've got a 64-bit version of VS2010 (do they have one?)

I also found [this](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VC/microsoft.public.vc.atl/2007-09/msg00114.html) which was an instance of someone passing a pointer to void, not a pointer to pointer to void.  You didn't show what type _PDM is, so I can't tell whether you declared it correctly (although you should've gotten a compiler warning if that was the case.)

Editted to add:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ole32.lib")

#define UNICODE
#define STRICT
#include <windows.h>
#include <activdbg.h>

#include <iostream>
using std::wcout;
using std::hex;
using std::endl;

int main(void)
{
    HRESULT hr;

    IProcessDebugManager *ppdm = NULL;
    IDebugApplication *pda = NULL;
    IClassFactory *pcf = NULL;
    DWORD cook = 0;

    CoInitialize(NULL);

    hr = CoGetClassObject(CLSID_ProcessDebugManager, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        NULL, IID_IClassFactory, (LPVOID *)&pcf);
    wcout << L"CoGetClassObject: " << std::hex << hr << endl;
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    hr = pcf->CreateInstance(0, IID_IProcessDebugManager32, (LPVOID *)&ppdm);
    wcout << L"CreateInstance: " << std::hex << hr << endl;
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto done;
    pcf->Release();

    hr = ppdm->CreateApplication(&pda);
    wcout << L"CreateApplication: " << std::hex << hr << endl;
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    ppdm->AddApplication(pda, &cook);
    pda->SetName(L"Moosh!");
    ppdm->RemoveApplication(cook);
    pda->Release();
    ppdm->Release();
done:
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

No real error checking, doesn't do anything but test one basic function, etc., but this doesn't throw any errors.  You didn't provide any detail as to what "doesn't work" means, and as I think I mentioned, I don't know how to use this stuff, but I can at least get an IProcesDebugManager and an IDebugApplication with this code.

Comment: No, it's 32 bit throughout, and all the types are correct.  But thanks for answering, at least.

Comment: I can't imagine why this works but I wrote up a test app using plain old C++ and CoCreateInstance and it fails with E_INVALIDARG like you got.  Then, after some Googling, I found a suggestion to use CoGetClassObject and IClassFactory::CreateInstance, so I tried that, and it worked!  So see if that works for you.  (I didn't try doing anything with the objects, but I could call IProcessDebugManager32::AddApplication and get back S_OK.

Answer (score 0):

E_INVALIDARG usually indicates passing an incorrect argument to the function! It usually isn't very clear what went wrong, i think this is an artifact of the way CLR and COM interact.

IProcessDebugManager appears to be a CLR Interface see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1ktkdaz%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Parameter 4 appears to be a CLR Interface, not an REFIID, however i can't be sure, since i don't know what language your using as i do not recognize the use of 'nil'; C# uses 'null', C++/CLI uses 'nullptr', and VB uses 'Nothing'.

IIDs are GUIDs, which are represented as strings, could your compiler be converting the CLR type to a string and passing that? My best guess is that COM wants a real GUID for the REFIID, and can't parse whatever IProcessDebugManager.ToString() spits out.

Comment: No CLR here.  This is Delphi code, and my code is correct.  The problem is that the GUID isn't properly registered, so COM can't find it.